# Java IoC Container Most Similar to Autofac

Tags: c#, java, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm a .NET developer primarily but am looking to use IoC in a Java project.

I have strong familiarity with Autofac. Is there an IoC container for Java that is substantially similar to Autofac in the way it is built, configured, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything similar. Autofac is quite unique and rely strongly on lambdas.

I could only recommend you [google guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), which is more similar to ninject. IMO it's quite powerful, easy to pick and fun to code.

Answer (score 0):

Check apache zest
https://zest.apache.org

It's application context is simmilar to the autofac builder

UPDATE: Apache Zest was renamed to Apache Polygene in early 2017, to avoid confusion with Eclipse Zest. https://polygene.apache.org